# How to append arguments in Ansible's ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible, arguments, parameter-passing, ansible-2.x

Ansible internally uses ssh to connect to a remote host.

I want to pass multiple arguments to ansible's ssh like below:

```
"ssh .... user@target <want my args here>"
```

I tried `ansible_ssh_common_args` & `ansible_ssh_extra_args` in the ansible host file but both of them put my arguments before instead of after the user@target as you see below:

```
"ssh ... <my args show here> user@target"
```

Can you please suggest what should i do to the ansible host file inorder to get my arguments after user@host for ssh ? Kindly help !

> ansible --version
>
> ansible 2.7.1
>
> config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
>
> configured module search path =
>   [u'/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules',
>   u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
>
> ansible python module location =
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
>
> executable location = /bin/ansible
>
> python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) [GCC 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding your arguments after user@target instead of before? It would be helpful for you to [edit] your question to show the actual command that you're trying to get it to run.

Comment: I'm loosing hope on this!! creating a new post for this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665640/ansible-fails-to-construct-desired-ssh-command] which includes answers to your question. Need an ansible expert please !!