# Ansible fails to construct desired ssh command

Tags: ssh, ansible

My organisation has a policy in place that allows "only" the below ssh command to work.

```
ssh -i /tmp/private.key -t user2@host2 bash --noprofile
```

I tried to modify the ansible inventory host file to construct the above ssh. See my ansible host file below:

```
host2 ansible_ssh_common_args="-t -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" ansible_shell_executable=sh ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/private.key  USER_RUN=user2
```

I also tried the below but they too fail

```
ansible_shell_executable=/bin/bash
ansible_ssh_extra_arg=.....
```

My ansible version is:

```
ansible --version

ansible 2.7.1

  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

  configured module search path = [u'/home/user1/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']

  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible

  executable location = /bin/ansible

  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

In debug i see that the ssh constructed by ansible does not have

> bash --noprfile

after user2@target2

Please help provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you can set the remote shell for specific hosts via

**Inventory**

```
some_host  ansible_shell_executable="/bin/bash --noprofile"
other_host ansible_shell_executable="/bin/bash --noprofile"
```

or globally via

**ansible.cfg**

```
executable = /bin/bash --noprofile
```

More information can be found in the ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html?highlight=ansible_shell_executable#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

Please note, that ansible additionally does `sftp` transfers under the hood.

IMHO if you want to use ansible in your organisation, it would be reasonable to change the policy.

Comment: if we leave / ignore --noprofile for now can we get ansible to construct just the bash after the user2@host2 ? Please let me know how ?

Comment: Corrected my answer

Comment: if you look at the original post i had already mentioned ansible_shell_executable=/bin/bash not working which is, I hope what you are suggesting ? Correct me if I m wrong ?

Comment: Yes, give my second solution, the global setting via `ansible.cfg` a try.

Comment: I cant edit / effect the global configuration as my ansible connects to other servers which do not require the ssh command we are trying to populate. It would have been great if we could have found a fix for my local playbook only.

Comment: Also, if there is a solution of only including the bash and not --noprofile ... that would do too!! Please suggest.

Comment: i tried the suggestion but that too fails. --noprofile is not working at all and hence i m removing it from my ssh command requirement. I have narrowed this down to until here -> Ansible constructs ssh -i /tmp/private.key -t user2@host2 bash -c. If we can remove the -c in the end then I am able to connect successfully. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: I think you can't remove the `-c` because this option tells the shell i.e. `bash` which command(s) to execute. This is not an interactive shell so the `-c` option must be specified.

Comment: My organisation disables anyone to fire any command using ssh; hence the -c option fails; so to conclude i guess ansible cannot me made to construct the working ssh implemented on our servers ?

Comment: Yes, if you are not able to run commands directly over ssh, ansible is not a solution for you. You can then for example go with puppet but there you have to install an agent on every server which then executes the commands.